# Octave: exporting a matrix to a file

Tags: matrix, export, octave

I'm guessing there is a simple solution to this, but I primarily use octave to solve systems of equations interactively [online](https://octave-online.net/). The problem is that the output from my current problem is too large to easily copy (by hand or into another file using copy/paste), and I am unsure how to export it. Text, LaTeX, .csv, or even something else would be fine, but it seems that exporting it would be useful.

The issue is that the screen breaks up the output such that it is difficult to read/copy without error. Code below (the matrix C is what I wish to export):

```
syms a b c q r s t x
A = [ 1 , -x*a, -x*(1-a); -x*b, 1, -x*(1-b); -x*c, -x*(1-c), 1]
Ainv = inv(A)

B = [t + q; t+ r; t+s]

C = Ainv*B
```

I have tried the save command, but it doesn't appear to do anything that I can tell. Ex: `save temp.txt, C` simply restates the command, but doesn't appear to give indication of saving to my computer (or even opportunity to do so/ask permission to save it someplace).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `@sym/latex` so it's easy to get latex:

```
octave:> latex (C)
\left[\begin{matrix}\left(q + t\right) \left(\frac{a b x^{2}}{- a b x^{2} + 1} - \frac{\left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(\frac{a x}{- a b x^{2} + 1} \left(- b x^{2} \left(- a + 1\right) - x \left(- b + 1\right)\right) - x \left(- a + 1\right)\right) \left(- \frac{b x \left(- a c x^{2} - x \left(- c + 1\right)\right)}{- a b x^{2} + 1} + c x\right)}{- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)} + 1\right) + \left(r + t\right) \left(\frac{a x}{- a b x^{2} + 1} + \frac{\left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(- a c x^{2} - x \left(- c + 1\right)\right) \left(\frac{a x}{- a b x^{2} + 1} \left(- b x^{2} \left(- a + 1\right) - x \left(- b + 1\right)\right) - x \left(- a + 1\right)\right)}{\left(- a b x^{2} + 1\right) \left(- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)\right)}\right) - \frac{\left(s + t\right) \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(\frac{a x}{- a b x^{2} + 1} \left(- b x^{2} \left(- a + 1\right) - x \left(- b + 1\right)\right) - x \left(- a + 1\right)\right)}{- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)}\\\left(q + t\right) \left(\frac{b x}{- a b x^{2} + 1} - \frac{\left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(- b x^{2} \left(- a + 1\right) - x \left(- b + 1\right)\right) \left(- \frac{b x \left(- a c x^{2} - x \left(- c + 1\right)\right)}{- a b x^{2} + 1} + c x\right)}{\left(- a b x^{2} + 1\right) \left(- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)\right)}\right) + \left(r + t\right) \left(\frac{1}{- a b x^{2} + 1} + \frac{\left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(- a c x^{2} - x \left(- c + 1\right)\right) \left(- b x^{2} \left(- a + 1\right) - x \left(- b + 1\right)\right)}{\left(- a b x^{2} + 1\right)^{2} \left(- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)\right)}\right) - \frac{\left(s + t\right) \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(- b x^{2} \left(- a + 1\right) - x \left(- b + 1\right)\right)}{\left(- a b x^{2} + 1\right) \left(- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)\right)}\\\frac{\left(q + t\right) \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(- \frac{b x \left(- a c x^{2} - x \left(- c + 1\right)\right)}{- a b x^{2} + 1} + c x\right)}{- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)} - \frac{\left(r + t\right) \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(- a c x^{2} - x \left(- c + 1\right)\right)}{\left(- a b x^{2} + 1\right) \left(- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)\right)} + \frac{\left(s + t\right) \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right)}{- x^{2} \left(a c x - c + 1\right) \left(b x \left(a - 1\right) + b - 1\right) + \left(a b x^{2} - 1\right) \left(c x^{2} \left(a - 1\right) + 1\right)}\end{matrix}\right]
```

which can be rendered to

[image: rendered]